# Previous month expression

Tags: qlikview, qliksense, qlik-expression

I need help to get a dynamic expression for the previous month (December 2022) compared to the current year's month, January 2023.

Perhaps the attached might provide some more clarity.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your data format a bit but in general you should be able to use something like:

```
= sum( {< Month = {"$(=MonthStart(AddMonths(Today(), - 1)))"} >} Sales)
```

The [set analysis](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/November2022/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/ChartFunctions/SetAnalysis/set-analysis-expressions.htm) will filter the `Sales` and will be sum only values for which `Month` is the month start of the previous month (based on [Today()](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/November2022/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/DateAndTimeFunctions/today.htm) function result)